# Launching react-native-navigation screen from Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

Is there a way to launch a specific react-native-navigation screen from Android side  for example with an intent?

Something like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RNNScreen.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to register a fragment and then consume it in the JS side with `externalComponent`. Take a look at [External Component documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/docs-externalComponent/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually wanted to access a screen that I created in JS. But I will try the other way around.